# What does an underscore between two variable mean?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What does an underscore between two variables mean?

for example:  `{ "#{type}_#{data['blah']}" : "#{data['blahblah']}"  }`

Comment: Your question is unclear: there is only one underscore in the code you posted, and it is not between two variables, it is between a closing curly brace `}` and an octothorpe `#`, neither of which are legal in a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's double-quoted [string literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) and [symbol literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) allow interpolation via `#{...}`. It works like a placeholder. The result of an expression given within the parentheses is converted to a string and inserted at the given position:

```
"1 + 2 = #{1 + 2}"
#=> "1 + 2 = 3"
```

Back to your question:

> What does an underscore between two variables mean?

Within a string, an underscore is a literal underscore, i.e. `_`.

Your code creates a hash with dynamically created symbol key and string value:

```
type = 'foo'
data = { 'blah' => 'bar', 'blahblah' => 'baz' }

{ "#{type}_#{data['blah']}": "#{data['blahblah']}" }
#=> {:foo_bar=>"baz"}
```

There was a minor typo in your code: the `:` must not have a trailing space.

Furthermore, interpolation is not needed if the string contains nothing else. If `data['blahblah']` is a string, you can just write:

```
{ "#{type}_#{data['blah']}": data['blahblah'] }
```

And otherwise:

```
{ "#{type}_#{data['blah']}": data['blahblah'].to_s }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it is not specific to Rails. It is just string concatenation. Basically, `type = "foo"` and `data['blah'] = bar` then, you would end up with:

```
{ "foo_bar" : "whatever is in the data['blahblah']" }
```

Comment: The term is "string interpolation", btw :)